# Any ideas on how to get this TV faded color effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've been trying to get this effect in Photoshop. I thought about creating 3 semi-transparent layers with the same image and having the images slightly unaligned (to give that ghost or faded trace). Then changing the hue in blue, red and yellow (one for each color shown on the picture) and for the natural colors (face) adding a 4th layer with an original image but desaturating it just a bit. I tried this idea but couldn't replicate the effect, so I want see if any of you have better ideas.

Note: I don't care about the horizontal lines shown on the pic, just to get the faded effect or those 3 colors.

[image: sample image]

---

Alright so I got it going. On the "Layers" pane I selected the "Channels" tab. Selected each color channel and shift the image just a bit.

Thank you @Lèse majesté. For some reason this didn't work last night I had an error saying that channels could not me moved but thanks to your answer i tried once again and now it works.

I tried to post a sample of what i made but i dont't have 10 reputation points to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to control each channel separately, make three layers with the same content. In the blending option, enable only one channel for each of these layers as shown below and disable the other two.

[image]

After creating three layers for each of the three channels, you can control them separately. You can use the filter>sketch>halftone pattern to get the horizontal lines. I did a quick simulation of what I'm talking. Here's the result. Be creative with other filters like blurr and you should be able to get it perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

That effect is produced because the registration for the red, green, and blue channels are off. The easiest way to reproduce the effect is to the reproduce the cause. Shift your red channel to the left and your blue channel to the right.